# Python How to check for no return

Tags: python, if-statement, diff

In python I want to diff two files using commands.getoutput('diff a.txt b.txt') and if they are the same, print "Success!". How would I go about writing an if statement that is satisfied if they are the same?

Comment: How much of the python book / tutorial did you read ? :D

Comment: diff is a bad choice for this -- if you only want to know if the files match, you can use `cmp`, which is both faster and more memory efficient. Also, checking the exit status is more canonically correct (and faster, albeit trivially so) than processing output as a string.

Comment: `commands` is _also_ a bad choice for this, being deprecated in new Python releases; the `subprocess` module is canonical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = commands.getoutput('diff a.txt b.txt')
if len(result) == 0:
   print 'Success'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is faster -- it will determine that the files are non-identical on the first difference, rather than reading the entirety of both of them and calculating a diff. It also correctly handles files with whitespace or unprintable characters in their names, and will continue to work with future versions of Python after the `commands` module is removed:

```
import subprocess
if subprocess.Popen(['cmp', '-s', '--', 'a.txt', 'b.txt']).wait() == 0:
  print 'Files are identical'
```

If the use of `diff` was a contrived example and your real goal *was* to determine whether output was given, you can do this with Popen also:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['diff', '--', 'a.txt', 'b.txt'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
(stdout, _) = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    print 'Process exited with error code %r' % p.returncode
if stdout:
    print 'Process emitted some output: \n%s' % stdout
else:
    print 'Process emitted no output'
```

Checking `returncode` is particularly important in UNIX tools where it can be necessary to distinguish between cases where no-output means success and where a failure occurred; simply looking at output will not always let you make this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

don't use commands use os, that is much better...

```
import os

os.system("diff a.txt b.txt" + "> diffOutput")
fDiff = open("diffOutput", 'r')
output = ''.join(fDiff.readlines())
if len(output) == 0:
        print "Success!"
else:
   print output

fDiff.close()
```

Comment: @TJD I think presenting alternative solutions is reasonable, considering that the `commands` module is deprecated since 2.6, and there was no reason given as to why `commands` is a requirement.

Comment: @Wilduck, sure I agree about alternate solutions.  But the crux of this particular question is 'how do i deal with running commands and detecting that nothing gets sent to stdout'

Comment: @TJD "How do I use foo to do bar" questions are generally misguided anyhow, as opposed to "what's the best way to do bar?" -- foo may be the wrong tool for the job. This is less true in cases where there can be compelling external reasons to use foo (a programming language or framework, for instance)... but not so much here.

Comment: Why `output = ''.join(fDiff.readlines())`?  Why not `if fDiff.read(1): print "Success"`?

Comment: If you really want to present an alternative, you should use `subprocess` then, that's what Python recommends. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `filecmp`?

```
import filecmp

diff = filecmp.cmp('a.pdf','b.pdf')
if diff:
    print('Success!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `commands.getoutput`? This module has been [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html) since python 2.6. Also, you can compare files with just python.

```
file_1_path = 'some/path/to/file1' 
file_2_path = 'some/path/to/file2'

file_1 = open(file_1_path)
file_2 = open(file_2_path)

if file_1.read() == file_2.read():
    print "Success!"

file_1.close()
file_2.close()
```

Given two paths to different files, `open` them, then, compare the results from `read`ing them both in to strings.

Comment: One downside to this implementation -- it requires the entirety of both files to fit into memory at once.